# can we store our Sql lite database-phonegap android?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cordova

can we store our Sql lite database in the assets folder for the Phonegap project?

I have already implemented an android project.i want to use the same DB for the Phonegap project.

can i use it? or  else what is the alternative and what is the procedure for it?

I have searched for the past 2 days .i did not get any proper answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include the sqlite db in the assets folder but on first run of the application you'll need to move it to the right directory so the webview can open the database. There is a plugin and description of how to do exactly this at:

http://gauravstomar.blogspot.ca/2011/08/prepopulate-sqlite-in-phonegap.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+GauravSTomarBootstrappingIntelligence+(Gaurav+S+Tomar+:+Bootstrapping+Intelligence)

Alternatively you could include your DB as a .sql file and execute the file the first time you start your app:

http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.ca/2011/12/on-fourth-day-of-phonegapping-creating.html

Comment: thank you,Simon MacDonald Sir.i will try it out and hope i am successful in it.and will let you know about the my status.

Comment: Simon MacDonald Sir,this is my 1st Phonegap application and i am using Cordova 2.5.0,hope its not a problem. Or would you suggest me to start with the lower versions?

Sir one more doubt,how should we code the following for phonegap?...... 
**table_instance_name = db.method_of_the_details_from the_table(id);
Column_instance = method_of_the_details_from the_table.get(0).get("column_name");**

Answer (score 1):

My current MyPhoneGapActivity looks like this

```
package com.rkadukar.database;

import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MyPhoneGapActivity extends DroidGap {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}
```

Where do I add the code to copy the db file from Assets folder to the data/data/... folder for my application.

As per my understanding once the database is copied I can then delete the file and use the native PhoneGap storage API to read my imported database but in that case why do we need this plugin https://github.com/brodyspark/PhoneGap-SQLitePlugin-Android

Can someone kindly detail the steps required to

1. Copy the database from the assets folder to the data/data/.. folder
2. Read the copied database and perform operations on it.

Comment: Rahul Kadukar,checkout [**this**](http://gauravstomar.blogspot.ca/2011/08/prepopulate-sqlite-in-phonegap.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+GauravSTomarBootstrappingIntelligence+(Gaurav+S+Tomar+:+Bootstrapping+Intelligence)) ..inspite reading it,if you don't get the flow comment here ...will answer your questions...in detail

Comment: Hi user, I am using PhoneGap for development and hence the only Java code that I have, is the one mentioned above in my comment. From what I understand it is going to load the file called index.html when the application is started.

I want to copy the database from assets to data/data/... folder, so should I add the code from Gaurav's post before my onloadUrl ?

Comment: yes......HOPE U UNDERSTAND THIS PROPERLY..  'public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
try
        {
            String pName = this.getClass().getPackage().getName();
            this.copy("ABC.db","/data/data/"+pName+"/databases/");
            this.copy("0000000000000001.db","/data/data/"+pName+"/databases/file__0/");
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
         e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }`

Comment: Well I did exactly as you had mentioned and wrote the logic before onloadUrl and it is not giving any visible error. I wanted to ask, do I need to copy both my database and the 000000000000001 file ?

If yes, what should be the contents of the 000000000000001 file ?

Comment: Rahul Kadukar,no you need not copy any thing...go to the file explorer and check in the data base path if u=your DB is available.....when i implemented it i get a warning and till today,i get it...but we are able o access the DB....go ahead!!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patience and time, I made a noob mistake and the db file which I wanted to copy was inside assets/www/ folder instead of assets folder. 

Will try to read the DB using PhoneGap Storage and let you know, but thanks a lot.

Comment: yeah...we tend to do that...as we access all the files from assets/www/..even i had that confusion...my pleasure helping you!!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28977/discussion-between-user-and-rahul-kadukar)